# why border-width property not styling my html?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

why border-width not applied css is not working?

Below is my code:

**CSS:**

```css
  {
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

try to embed between head with proper `<style></style>` attribute.

#### Note: The "border-width" property does not work if it is used alone. Use the "border-style" property to set the borders first.

---

[Reference Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.one {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="one">Some text.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> The "border-width" property does not work if it is used alone. Use the "border-style" property to set the borders first.</p>

</body>
</html>
```